# Finding all coordinates around the player in a range

Tags: javascript

I am making a game where the player can move around a grid, but they can only move to areas around them in a certain range. I need to check if where the player is trying to move to is actually somewhere they are allowed to go.

My code so far is this:

```js
const generateMoveableAreas = (playerX, playerY, range) => {
  const moveableAreas = [];
  for (let i = range; i > 0; i--) {
    moveableAreas.push(
      { x: playerX + i, y: playerY },
      { x: playerX + i, y: playerY + i },
      { x: playerX, y: playerY + i },
      { x: playerX - i, y: playerY + i },
      { x: playerX - i, y: playerY },
      { x: playerX - i, y: playerY - i },
      { x: playerX, y: playerY - i },
      { x: playerX + i, y: playerY - i },
    );
  }
  return moveableAreas;
};
```

This works correctly if the range is 1, but if the range is 2 or more, a problem occurs.
Here is an example of what the grid looks like - 0 is not reachable, R is reachable, U is *should be reachable, but isn't*, and P is player. The player has a range of 2.

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 R U R U R 0 
0 U R R R U 0 
0 R R P R R 0 
0 U R R R U 0 
0 R U R U R 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

What I need is for all those U spots to be R.

Comment: Should the spots marked as `U` be reachable from the players current position? If yes, they are corretctly unreachable as they are not with a range of 2 moves or am I missing something?

Comment: Your code is only adding orthogonal and diagonal moves, so your "reachable areas" are a chess Queen's move away within range.

Comment: @empiric Yes, they should be reachable but the current code doesn't allow them to be.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Yes I know that, I am trying to make the other spots marked U reachable as well but I am having trouble.

Comment: Define "reachable"? Can the player move diagonally, or in other words, does a diagonal move count as 1 "step"?

Comment: @Cerbrus yes, they can move diagonally

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can massively simplify your code.
Seeing as all spots within <range> are reachable, you can just use the range as offsets for some loops, looping over all reachable x/y coordinates:

```js
const generateMoveableAreas = (playerX, playerY, range) => {
  const moveableAreas = [];
  for (let x = -range; x <= range; x++) {
    for (let y = -range; y <= range; y++) {
      moveableAreas.push({ x: playerX + x, y: playerY + y })
    }
  }
  
  return moveableAreas;
};

const movable = generateMoveableAreas(0, 0, 2);
console.log(movable);
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through all the spots in range:

```
const generateMoveableAreas = (playerX, playerY, range) => {
  const moveableAreas = [];
  for (let i = Math.max(0, playerX - range); i <= playerX + range; i++) {
    for (let j = Math.max(0, playerY - range);  j <= playerY + range; j++) {
      moveableAreas.push(
        { x: i, y: j },
      );
    }
  }
  return moveableAreas;
};
```

I added a check to make sure it doesn't try to add moves that are out of range (< 0), but you'll have to add additional checks to make sure you don't try to go out of range to the right or down, since you haven't shown how large the grid is.

Answer (score 0):

The available squares are basically a square of range x 2 + 1
This means that you could do something like :

```
for (let i = playerX - range; i <= playerX + range; i++) {
  for (let j = playerY - range; j <= playerY + range; j++) {
    moveableAreas.push({ x: i, y: j });
  }
}
```